# how to check if one or more files are selected for file upload

Tags: php, upload, selected

I am trying to check if one or more files are selected for file upload but i do not succeed in it.
This is the form input:

```
<input class="form-control-file" type="file" name="new_image[]" value="" multiple />
```

And my php:

```
if($_FILES["new_image"]["error"] == 0 ) { // if one or more file(s) are selected
    echo 'file selected';
```

I do not get the echo back...

Comment: Please describe more. What you want finally? Check this on the front end, i.e. with ajax, react, vue or other technology.

Comment: I just want to check if at least one or more files are selected for uploading...

Comment: I think you need check this on the front end, This is a much better option. If you want to display a notification of appointment.

Comment: @OktamYaqubov Checking for uploaded files in the front end is meaningless if you're interested in that information in the back end code, for example to execute a segment of code or perform some logic if no files are present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked if you gave your form tag enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute to allow file uploads?

When multiple files are uploaded the error attribute is sent as an array, take a look at below snippet.

```
foreach ($_FILES["new_image"]['error'] as $key => $error) {
            if($error === 0){
                echo 'file selected';
                break;
            }
        }
```